# Dovecot and two places for messages

Tags: dovecot

We use Dovecot with Maildir uncompressed storage, bu also want to play with compression and/or Dbox storage format. Is there any way I can keep one mailbox or one mail domain as "new" format (say, Dbox), while remainings to be keep as it was before (old way = Maildir).

I can see there is ALT mail location but not sure if this is what I need: say, I have a mailbox in "old" storage location, and then new message dilevered to it, will it be put to the old location or it'll be put into new location the mailbox then be "shared" betwoorn two locations?

Please advice the best way!